# Does Husk Have to Pull off Her Shed Skin?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I am currently trying to catch up on *X-Men*, and was curious about the character  of Paige Guthrie, who uses the code name 'Husk', due to her mutant  ability to shed her skin. However, I have noticed through several pictures that she is shown pulling off the skin.

I am just curious , does she HAVE to pull off the shed skin or will it just fall off on its  own?

Comment: I hear it can also be removed with Toad's spit

Comment: If you are the same person as [this user](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/73056/xfan25), it would be best for you to merge your accounts by following the instructions [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In particular, your approved edit [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/143438/revisions) would probably be considered as conflicting with the author’s intent if coming from another user.

Comment: Whichever method is used, the real question is how the hell she removes it without also taking off her clothes.  Technically she should be going into battle naked, to make it easier to shed...

Answer (score 2):

As of *X-Men: Regenesis Vol. 1*, Paige has been shown as spontaneously molting under high stress with patches of her skin falling off, each with different forms below.

[image: Molting Paige]

In addition, the story has Toad forcibly removing layers of skin from Husk, suggesting that, at least in this molting state, the skin does not have to be removed voluntarily. This has been stated to be a new development in her powers, as *Wolverine and the X-Men #41* states that it's due to a "[secondary mutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_mutation)".

[image: Toad tearing off Husk's husks]

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it requires her to pull the top layer of skin off her body to expose the new skin and access the ability. it can be removed via trauma or impacts. I haven't seen it just "fall off" though.

Comment: Could you add relevant panels to make this answer better?